# google-maps directions python

Tags: python, google-maps

Ive been trying to get the new Google maps API working to print directions from point A to B but am getting the following error.

(direct from there [website](http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/))

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
gmaps = GoogleMaps(api_key)
```

but ive changed to clint so is now

```
from googlemaps import Client
gmaps = Client(api_key)
address = "Adelaide, South Australia, Australia"
destination = "Stirling, South Australia, Australia"
directions = gmaps.directions(address, destination)
for step in directions['Directions']['Routes'][0]['Steps']:
    print step['descriptionHtml']
```

The error I get is

```
C:\>gmap.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\gmap.py", line 10, in <module>
    for step in dirs['Directions']['Routes'][0]['Steps']:
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Fixed typo still no change

Comment: I didn't think it would fix it, but it makes it easier to paste your code. (Original comment deleted)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all that wonder getting directions from point A to Point B can be done

```
import json, urllib
from urllib import urlencode
import googlemaps
start = "Bridgewater, Sa, Australia"
finish = "Stirling, SA, Australia"

url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?%s' % urlencode((
            ('origin', start),
            ('destination', finish)
 ))
ur = urllib.urlopen(url)
result = json.load(ur)

for i in range (0, len (result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'])):
    j = result['routes'][0]['legs'][0]['steps'][i]['html_instructions'] 
    print j
```

There are 2 possible routes for this trip but by defalut this is fastest